# Writing a CSV file into a PDF document

Tags: python, csv, pdf, sqlite, reportlab

I have a python script that parses data from an SQLite DB file and writes it to a .csv file. I would like to write this data to a forensic style report in PDF format. I have already been able to create a template pdf with a heading, date, case number, and short paragraph on details. I was wondering how should I write the .csv file data into a table in the PDF. As shown i have tried iterating through the .csv file after reading it with csv.reader. I can write the initial headings into the file but it will not pull the data from the .csv file and write it. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
# Script to generate a PDF report after data has been parsed into .csv file

# import statements
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import portrait
import csv

# PDF document layout
canvas = canvas.Canvas("H:\College Fourth Year\Development Project\Final Year Project 2018\Forensic Reports\SMS Report.pdf", pagesize=letter)

canvas.setLineWidth(.3)
canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
canvas.drawString(30,750,'LYIT MOBILE FORENSICS DIVISION')
canvas.drawString(500,750,"Date: 12/02/2018")
canvas.line(500,747,595,747)
canvas.drawString(500,725,'Case Number:')
canvas.drawString(580,725,"10")
canvas.line(500,723,595,723)

# Introduction text
line1 = 'This forensic report on SMS data has been compiled by the forensic'
line2 = 'examiner in conclusion to the investigation into the RTA'
line3 = 'case which occured on 23/01/2018'
textObject = canvas.beginText(30, 700)
lines = [line1, line2, line3]
for line in lines:
    textObject.textLine(line)
canvas.drawText(textObject)

# File that must be written to report
data_file = 'H:\College Fourth Year\Development Project\Final Year Project 2018\ExtractedEvidence\smsInfo.csv'
c = canvas

# Function for importing data
def import_Data(data_file):
    smsInfo = csv.reader(open(data_file, "r"))
    for row in smsInfo:
        ID = row[0]
        Incoming_Number = row[1]
        Date_And_Time = row[2]
        Read = row[3]
        Sent_Replied = row[4]
        Body = row[5]
        Seen = [6]
        pdf_filename = 'SMS Data Report.pdf'
    generate_report(ID, Incoming_Number, Date_And_Time, Read, Sent_Replied, Body, Seen)

def generate_report(ID, Date_And_Time, Read, Sent_Replied, Body, Seen, pdf_filename):
    #c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_filename, pagesize=portrait(letter))



    import_Data(data_file)
canvas.save()


print("Forensic Report Generated!")
```

Comment: If you use backslashes in strings (`database = "H:\College Fourth Year\Development Project\Final Year Project 2018\mmssms.db"
`) you should either escape them (\\\) or use raw strings: `database = r"H:\College Fourth Year\Development Project\Final Year Project 2018\mmssms.db"`, or use slashes, I think that works too on Windows.

Comment: Not to be rude, but did you actually try anything to incorporate your db export script into your other script? The same way that you loop over the results of the select is the same way that you can loop over the lines of the CSV file.

Comment: I have tried but I don't know what i am doing wrong. my attempt is in the edit above.

Comment: You don't tell in your question what goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, I think i have almost cracked it but its giving an error saying that: canvas.save()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'save'. My updated code is shown above in the question.

Comment: You call `import_Data` from inside `generate_report` and `generate_report` from inside `import_Data`, which would be an infinite loop, but you don't actually call any of these two functions. I think you're just trying some guesses instead of actually trying to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something different. Recently I had to make a similar PDF files using data from csv file. I hope this help you:

```
# import statements
import requests
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape, legal, letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, Image, Spacer, PageBreak, Table, TableStyle 
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

import csv
import os

# Get de work directory 
cwd = os.getcwd() 

# Introduction text
line1 = 'This forensic report on SMS data has been compiled by the forensic'
line2 = 'examiner in conclusion to the investigation into the RTA'
line3 = 'case which occured on 23/01/2018'

#PDF document layout
table_style = TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.red),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.blue),
                       ('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.green),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ])
styles = getSampleStyleSheet() 
styleNormal = styles['Normal']
styleHeading = styles['Heading1']
styleHeading2 = styles['Heading2'] 
styleHeading.alignment = 1 # centre text (TA_CENTRE) 

#Configure style and word wrap
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'

# File that must be written to report
with open ('smsInfo.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    lista = list(reader)

headers = lista[0]

conteo = 1

for numRecord in range(1,len(lista)):

    record1 = lista[numRecord]

    data = list()
    emptyRecords = list()
    records = list()
    header = list()

    countRecords = 0

    for line in record1:

        if line == '':
            emptyRecords.append(line)           
        else:
            records.append(line)
            header.append(headers[countRecords])

            data.append([str(headers[countRecords]), str(line)])

        countRecords = countRecords + 1

    data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in data]
    t = Table(data2)
    t.setStyle(table_style)

    elements = []

    # Name of file
    fileName = cwd + '\\' + 'SMS Data Report' + '-' + str(conteo) + '.pdf'

    conteo = conteo + 1

    archivo_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(fileName, pagesize = letter, rightMargin = 40, leftMargin = 40, topMargin = 40, bottomMargin = 28)

    #Send the data and build the file
    elements.append(Paragraph(line1, styleNormal))
    elements.append(Paragraph(line2, styleNormal))
    elements.append(Paragraph(line3, styleNormal))
    elements.append(Spacer(inch, .25*inch))
    elements.append(t)

    archivo_pdf.build(elements)
    print 'Forensic Report Generated:', fileName
```

This code generate files like this one:

[PDF report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ihtx.jpg)

Comment: This has helped me so much, thankyou. I was wondering how i can write this under the table?: 'This forensic report on SMS data has been compiled by the forensic'
'examiner in conclusion to the investigation into the RTA'
'case which occurred on 23/01/2018'

Comment: You can add lines using append like this: elements.append(Paragraph('This forensic report on SMS data has been compiled by the forensic', styleNormal)). Write this below the line elements.append(t)

Comment: Fantastic!. Thank You. I will accept your answer now. :)

Comment: Great!!. I forgot mention that you can change the style of the line1, line2 or line3 text. Just change the elemnt styleNormal by sstyleHeading or styleHeading2. In line elements.append(Paragraph(line1, styleNormal))