# How to parse CSV or FDF data to a Python dictionary and inject into a template PDF form?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pdf, adobe, fdf

I have client data in a CRM that I need to use in automation of PDF form completion.

I have figured out CRM extraction to CSV, post extraction CSV manipulation, correct CSV parsing into FDF format and creation and saving of the new PDF file that *should* be populated with the data from the FDF. The code is supposed to open up a template form with field names that match the CSV and FDF files, inject the values for the fields and save it as a new file.

The problem I seem to be stuck on is that I cannot get the FDF data into the template. When I open the new saved PDF the feilds are blank. I've played with a few different approaches but I'm so far down the rabbit hole now that I think I've lost the ability to be objective.

I'm using pypdf 4.1.0 library as I saw that the dev had rolled PyPDF2 back into it.

Here is the code that I am working on currently. I've tried many different approaches but this is the cleanest version that represents the current status:

```
import csv
import os
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

# Read the CSV file
with open('acrobat_import.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    data = list(reader)

# Function to create the FDF file content
def create_fdf_content(row):
    fdf_content = """
    
%FDF-1.2
%����
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</F(template_form.pdf)/Fields[
    <</T(courseType)/V/{courseType}>>
    <</T(gender)/V/{gender}>>
    <</T(dateofbirth)/V({dateofbirth})>>
    <</T(preferredLanguage)/V/{preferredLanguage}>>
    <</T(LastName)/V({lastName})>>
    <</T(firstName)/V({firstName})>>
    <</T(middleName)/V({middleName})>>
    <</T(addressStreet)/V({addressStreet})>>
    <</T(addressCity)/V({addressCity})>>
    <</T(addressState)/V({addressState})>>
    <</T(addressCountry)/V({addressCountry})>>
    <</T(addressPostalCode)/V({addressPostalCode})>>
    <</T(phoneNumber)/V({phoneNumber})>>
    <</T(emailAddress)/V({emailAddress})>>
    <</T(studentSigDate)/V({studentSigDate})>>
    <</T(courseStartDate)/V({courseStartDate})>>
    <</T(courseEndDate)/V({courseEndDate})>>
    <</T(classHours)/V({classHours})>>
    <</T(numberOfStudents)/V({numberOfStudents})>>
    <</T(courseState)/V({courseState})>>
    <</T(courseCity)/V({courseCity})>>
    <</T(courseLanguage)/V/{courseLanguage}>>
    <</T(instructorNumber)/V({instructorNumber})>>
    <</T(instructorLastName)/V({instructorLastName})>>
    <</T(instructorFirstName)/V({instructorFirstName})>>
    <</T(instructorSigDate)/V({instructorSigDate})>>
    <</T(courseFee)/V({courseFee})>>
    <</T(examinerNumber)/V({examinerNumber})>>
    <</T(examinerLastName)/V({examinerLastName})>>
    <</T(examinerFirstName)/V({examinerFirstName})>>
    <</T(examinerSigDate)/V({examinerSigDate})>>]
    >> >>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
""".format(**row)
    return fdf_content    
    
# Loop through each row, create an FDF file
for row in data:
    if row['lastName'] and row['firstName']:
        # Create the FDF file
        fdf_filename = f"{row['lastName']}_{row['firstName']} - {row['courseType']}.fdf"
        with open(fdf_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(create_fdf_content(row))
        print(f"Created FDF file: {fdf_filename}")

# Open the template PDF
template_pdf = PdfReader("template_form.pdf", "rb")

# Create a dictionary from the fdf file
def parse_fdf_file(fdf_filename):
    fields = []
    with open(fdf_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fdf_file:
        lines = fdf_file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('<</T(') and '/V(' in line: # Does not account for radio button fields which have /V/ not /V()
                field_name = line.split('<</T(')[1].split(')')[0]
                field_value = line.split('/V(')[1].split(')')[0]
                fields.append({'field_name': field_name, 'field_value': field_value})
    return fields

# Import the FDF data into the template PDF
pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
page = template_pdf.pages[0]
fields = template_pdf.get_fields()
pdf_writer.add_page(page)
for field in fields:
    pdf_writer.update_page_form_field_values(0, field['field_name'], field['field_value'])

# Save the resulting PDF with the same name as the FDF file
pdf_filename = f"{row['lastName']}_{row['firstName']} - {row['courseType']}.pdf"
with open(pdf_filename, "wb") as pdf_file:
    pdf_writer.write(pdf_file)
print(f"Created PDF file: {pdf_filename}")
```

Validation of what I have here is that this code does create an FDF file in the correct format and I can manually import that FDF into the template form. That tells me that the FDF is being created correctly and therefore, the data, field names etc are correct and working.

I'm thinking that I may still be on an ineffective track with this though. I don't *need* and FDF file, I just need the data in the CSV file to go into the template form and be saved. The CSV has multiple rows with 1 clients data on each row. It occured to me while reading the pypdf docs that the FDF step is wasteful and quite possibly problematic and that the FDF form was not the same entity as a python dictionary.

So, I'm here to ask for input and help. What is the most efficient or at least the most effective way to parse the CSV and inject into the template form?

I should add that the template form has mostly text form fields but some radio button groups. As far as I can tell, the FDF only handles these differently with the value for a text field preceded by /V( and a radio button value by /V/ . I haven't yet fixed lines 75:77 as I wanted to get the feedback from here first.

I did read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745947/writing-a-csv-file-into-a-pdf-document) and a whole lot of others but I'm not looking to create a whole PDF, I need to utilise a template form with fields that must be populated.

EDIT/UPDATE:
Switched to parsing the CSV directly but getting 'Error: key must be PdfObject':

```
import csv
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

# Define CSV and PDF template file names
CSV_FILE = "acrobat_import.csv"
PDF_TEMPLATE = "pdf_import_template.pdf"

def process_csv_pdf(csv_file, pdf_template):
    try:
        # 1. Read the CSV data into a dictionary
        with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            csv_data = list(reader)           # Read the data as dictionaries

            print("CSV Data:", csv_data)

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"Error: CSV file '{csv_file}' not found.")
        return
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading CSV file: {e}")
        return

    # 2. Process each row in the CSV
    for row in csv_data:
        try:
            # 3. Prepare variables for file naming
            last_name = row.get('lastName', '')
            first_name = row.get('firstName', '')
            course_type = row.get('courseType', '')

            if not all([last_name, first_name, course_type]):
                print(f"Warning: Skipping row due to missing data: {row}")
                continue  # Skip rows with missing fields

            # 4. Create output file name
            output_filename = f"{last_name}_{first_name} - {course_type}.pdf"
            print(f"Processing: {output_filename}")

            # 5. Fill the PDF template
            reader = PdfReader(pdf_template)
            writer = PdfWriter()
            page = reader.pages[0]
            
             # Get form fields 
            fields = reader.get_fields(0) 
            if fields:
                field_map = {field.get("/T"): field for field in fields.values()} # Create a mapping

                for field_name in row:  # Iterate over your CSV keys directly
                    if field_name in field_map:
                        pdf_field = field_map[field_name]
                         # Debugging: 
                        print(type(pdf_field))  # Print the type of the PdfObject
                        print(pdf_field)        # Print the representation of the field object

                        pdf_field["/V"] = row[field_name]  # Direct update attempt
                        writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.add_page(page), pdf_field.get("/T"), row[field_name]) # Note: Using .get("/T") for the key



            # 6. Save the output PDF
            with open(output_filename, 'wb') as output_file:
                writer.write(output_file)

            print(f"PDF created: {output_filename}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing row: {row}, Error: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_csv_pdf(CSV_FILE, PDF_TEMPLATE)
```

Comment: The FDF exactly matches that exported from a populated example of the template and when recreated, can be manually imported into the template file. In fact, The code as it stands will create separate FDF files with the correct naming, and I can double-click each FDF and it will directly import into the template. I would just have to manually save each each one but that is not my goal if I can avoid it.

As far as I can tell, the issue I face is in getting the data from the CSV or FDF into a dictionary that pypdf can read to insert into the template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a rather straightforward operation to open the CSV, iterate each row, and fill in a new PDF with PyPDF... but it will probably have some kind of problem... 'cause PDFs.

From the latest PyPDF documentation on [filling-out a form](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/forms.html#filling-out-forms), I made a script which will read an input CSV, that looks like:

```
| First_name | Last_name | Home_address   | County     | Birthday  |
|------------|-----------|----------------|------------|-----------|
| Foo        | Bar       | 123 Main St    | Multnomah  | 1/1/2000  |
| Baz        | Baker     | 456 Second Ave | Washington | 6/21/1999 |
```

then iterate each row and call a function to open the original PDF, copy it (based on First_name), and fill it in.  I used the csv module's DictReader because I can just pass the dict row directly to the update_page_form_field_values method:

```py
import csv
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter


def new_pdf_from(row: dict[str, str]):
    reader = PdfReader("form.pdf")
    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.append(reader)

    writer.update_page_form_field_values(
        writer.pages[0],
        row,
        auto_regenerate=False,
    )

    with open(f"output-{row['First_name']}.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
        writer.write(output_stream)


with open("data.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        new_pdf_from(row)
```

[image: PDFs filled out]

Comment: @KJ, works jus fine with 'Bar 世界'.

Comment: @KJ,  can you point to that Adobe recommendation? I'm still relatively new to PDF internals. I haven't really had to deal with encoding differences. I guess I got lucky in this instance that UTF-8 just worked. Looking at the difference between the original spec and Rev 2, UTF-8 was mentioned only 7 times vs. dozens for Rev 2.

Comment: I'm pursuing a similar path at the moment and still running into errors in the import to PDF. I'm a real novice at code (beyond YAML) and am only just venturing into Python now. Forums and AI are no substitute for experience though. That said, I do understand analysis and testing so I can figure out what works and what doesn't, just not how to fix the stuff that doesn't.

I've dropped the FDF and I can now parse the CSV into a dictionary (just with one row currently) and I'm getting 'Error: key must be a PdfObject' but I ran out of time at the end of last week to chase that down.

Comment: @TripitakaBC, if you think you'll go the route of directly inserting the data into the PDF, like I showed above, maybe accept this solution (not sure if you were already going down that path or if this solution inspired you), or just delete (close) the question as it no longer really needs/has a solution. Then open new questions as problems arise with the new approach. Good luck!

Comment: I've got some more time to work on this today but then I need to move it to 'interesting problem' status if I can't get it working. The FDF creation I had originally solves 90% of the workload. The other 10% is me just being irritated that I can't make it work and solve the whole problem. :-) - I'll come back and update later.

Comment: Well, I am deeply grateful! The above code does work to get most of the data across into the PDF template. It doesn't bring over the radio button fields but I can work on that. Also, for some strange reason, it completely ignores any formatting in the form fields themselves such as font size and alignment. If I click on the form field, it is represented correctly and when I click out of it, it returns to unformatted state.

I've marked the answer as accepted as the code does what I asked of it for the most part.

Comment: @TripitakaBC, the radio buttons should just be a matter of getting valid option text for the correct field name. I had an issue too with the formatting being off, but it was only one field in 300. If I were faced with that problem again, I'd try to delete and recreate the fields that didn't end up rendering correctly. I'm sure there's a correct solution to that problem, but being between the PDF creator and the PyPDF lib I'd probably get hacky and creative.

Comment: I'm a long way off being proficient enough to be 'creative' but this will sit as a project that interests me enough to learn when I can move it up the priority list. For me, it is all the fields that don't render correctly with the data but...the data does inject into the PDF which was the problem I was chasing down.